# Spring Boot Admin Console 2.0.4 How to have the wallboard unsecured?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin

I'm using Spring Boot Admin Console 2.0.4 (with Spring Boot 2.0.6) with security setup based on that provided in the reference guide http://codecentric.github.io/spring-boot-admin/2.0.4/#_securing_spring_boot_admin_server.  I can't see how to unsecure the wallboard page so that this is publicly accessible whilst securing the remaining pages.  Has anyone experience of doing this?